# Which is the most appropiate algorithm to use with Mlib for predicting prices

Tags: apache-spark, beginner

I am reading the docs of MLlib, but I am new with it and I don't know which would be the best algorithm to predict prices.

I have seen that with RandomRDDs I can use a generator for random numbers that follow a normal distribution.

In my case, this is not good enought, since the prices I want to simulate doesn't follow a normal distribution. The demand changes depending on if its daytime or night, so the prices also change. The seasonality also affects the demand and influence the resulting prices.

Because of that, I would need a model that I can feed with historical data in order to generate new prices for simulations that have "sense" depending on the day of the year or the hour (day/night) I want to simulate.

As I said, I'm looking for a solution with MLlib since I'm working with Spark. I'm blocked in finding the appropiate algorithm when reading the docs. I only would need a name or a few names in order to continue investigating (I, myself, can enrich later the answer in order to help other people that reach this post)

Comment: Welcome to the site, Mary!

Comment: I would start with Box-Jenkins seasonal modeling (an appropriate stationarity transformation, which you can do in a Spark dataframe, and an ARIMA model).